# Angular 2 - Set page/route http status code

Tags: angular, http-headers

Is it possible in Angular 2 to change the status of a page that is rendered to something other than 200?

For example, we have routes for both a "404" page, and a "500" page, and I want those routes to respond with the appropriate http status.

Google does something similar: going to www.google.com/thisisanerror, you can see in the network tab that that document returns a 404.

[image: Google 404 page]

Answer (score 1):

No.

Angular is a client side library. It can make HTTP requests (but they aren't directly connected to the URL shown in the address bar). It doesn't make HTTP responses. HTTP statuses are a feature of the response.

Comment: I realize it is a client side library, but was hoping there was some way to set http headers for certain routes.

Comment: There isn't. There isn't HTTP anything for a route.

Comment: @TimW you can achieve the same if you are using SSR with Angular