# Display 404 error code when URL doesn't exist from angular route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

When I search some random URLs from my angular application, in the network tag of any browser for that particular URL I am are status code as 200 OK. Instead when URL doesn't exists, I want to customize this to 404 not found. How can I do it

[200 status code the URL doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ytd.png)

Now I am displaying 404 error page but not sure how to change status code 200 to 404

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - Set page/route http status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863737/angular-2-set-page-route-http-status-code)